# Unchcked Cast Generics

Tags: java, casting, unchecked

In my code I have

`private E[] arrCirc;`

and in my constructor I have  `arrCirc = (E[]) new Object[capacity];`
but when I try to compile it I get an warning:

[unchecked] unchecked cast 
found   : java.lang.Object 
required: E[]

Error and I'm not sure why.

```
public class Array12<E> implements LimCapList<E>{

  private int size = 0;
  private int capacity = 0;
  private int front;
  private int back;
  private E[] arrCirc;

  public Array12(int capacity){
     if( capacity <= 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     arrCirc = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
     front = 0;
     back = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you make your `arrCirc` of type `Object[]` (like most [generic collections](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/e0e25ac28560/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) in openJDK do) ?

( and do `arrCirc =  new Object[capacity];` )

Otherwise for the warning, you can just use SupressWarning.

```
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Array12(int capacity){
             if( capacity <= 0)
               throw new IllegalArgumentException();
             arrCirc = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
             front = 0;
             back = 1;
          }
```

Comment: My assignment said I should only have a single argument constructor of type int. Otherwise I could use this.

Comment: I made my arrCirc into an Object[] type but I still get the warning.

Comment: @user in that case, you would not need the casting to `(E[])`.

Comment: I doubt this casting work. You cannot say that a array of object is Of type E[]. I think this is flawed.

Comment: @edalorzo There will be no casting if it's `Object[]` but the array should be private. It's like the array can contain anything  `Object[] arr = new Object[10];
     arr[1] = "kjdklsf";
     arr[2] = 1;`. Ofcourse it's not type safe ; You'll have to do type checking in your add, remove and get methods.

Comment: @Bala R in your code you create a new array of type object and then cast it to E[]. Java runtime will ensure at runtime that your array is of type E[] because arrays are reifiable types. Have you tried this code?

Comment: By making arrCirc of type `Object[]` you are only delaying the inevitable unsafe cast (`get(int index)` methods and alike will need to cast the variable). But +1 for the @SuppressWarnings.
@edalorzo, I agree that the cast is uggly and pointless, but E will be erased to Object anyway so it will work.

Comment: @edalorzo check line 89 in this code file http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html and check line 132 here http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/e0e25ac28560/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java  these are the two different ways in which it can be done.

Comment: @Bala R I gave it a try to your code and I see your point now. @Anthony Accioly I see the erasure now. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses Type Erasure to implement generics, so it can't know at Runtime what you mean with  (E[]), that's why you get the warning of a potentially unsafe cast.

Take a look at Sun (erm... Oracle) documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

You can always use `@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")` to make the warning go away.